# Convert date with timezone to UTC?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-fns

A quick question. I have a ISO string date:

```
2022-07-03T10:51:09+02:00
```

this date as you can see has timezone included (+02:00).

Question: How to convert it into `UTC` date? Using e.g. `date-fns` or `moment`?

Edit: Should I just simply add "02:00" hours to current date? So it would be `12:51:09`?

Answer (score 2):

Trivially [`new Date(isoString).toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), no libraries required.

```js
const input = "2022-07-03T10:51:09+02:00";
console.log(`${input} in UTC:\n${new Date(input).toISOString()}`);
```

Comment: Oh, so in the fact it should NOT be added, but subtracted! Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's 10:53 in +02:00, so 08:53 in +00:00.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, timezone is simply the representation of the same timestamp across different geographies (no. of seconds elapsed since unix time 0 is the same everywhere). So be careful while adding/removing time manually from the existing timestamp.

You can do that using `moment.js` like this:

```js
var someday = moment('2022-07-03T10:51:09+02:00');
console.log(someday.utc().format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```